# Change profile name via XML

Tags: deployment, profile, xml

Profile pushed out to production with incorrect standards naming convention.
Need to push this change via package / merge into branch. Really don't want to manually change the name.
Using the following :

existing profile name: ABC standard user

rename as: ABC Standard User

object name : ABC standard user.profile

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <custom>true</custom>
    <fullName>ABC Standard User</fullName>     
</Profile>
```

When trying to deploy getting:

```
All Component Failures:
1.  profiles/ABC standard user.profile -- Error: fullName specified in file does not match file name
```

Goal is to change the profile name from 'ABC standard user' to 'ABC Standard User' using a package for deployment to all environs. Has anyone had success with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. You need to use the [renameMetadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_renameMetadata.htm) function to make this kind of change, and there is no XML equivalent. You can either delete and recreate the profile, edit the profile in the UI, or use the method from above, perhaps with the Ant Migration Toolkit, which is antiquated, but should still work.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the confirmation.